# Flutter + Google Spreadsheets

Tags: android, flutter

I followed an article about a flutter app that is simply a Form filler that then sends to a google Spreadsheet and it works perfectly in the android emulator (Pixel 4):

https://medium.com/mindorks/storing-data-from-the-flutter-app-google-sheets-e4498e9cda5d

But when I 'flutter install' into my OnePlus 6 It does not submit the info to the spreadsheet when I press submit.

Any ideas to why could this happen?

Comment: Could you please post some codes?

Comment: could you show your code? Is impossible to guess as it could literally be anything.

Comment: have you even debugged your code? Did you added the internet permission?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla era eso. That was it! I did not add that permission before building. It is my first time with flutter. Appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure! Make sure to always include your code over questions here.